# How can I track how much data my Python program is sending / receiving over the network?

Tags: python, networking, monitoring

I have a Python program that queries multiple remote services (MongoDB, MySQL, etc). Is there a way to track how much data my program is transferring over the network either within the Python program or through some Linux utility?

Answer (score 0):

In python, you'd probably have to wrap things - it could be a bit of a challenge.

In Linux, the netstat program will probably do something that's at least related to what you want.